# OOM Killer strikes although overcommit_memory is set to 2

Tags: out-of-memory, embedded-linux

I have application running for hours in embedded Linux, when suddenly the OOM Killer jumps out.

I set `overcommit_memory=2` and `overcommit_ratio=50` to provoke the situation and catch the possible leaks, but the OOM Killer still strikes out!

To check that my settings are active, I asked for a big malloc and it really does return zero when I set `overcommit_memory=2`.

So, why is the OOM Killer still starting and what can I do to investigate the source of the problem?

Comment: I checked also (with the help of dmalloc library), that I do not eat memory. The malloc logs show that there is constant process of taking and returning of the same amount of memory, i.e. no issue seems to be...

Comment: All I can think of is that perhaps something other than `malloc` is eating memory. Some kind of buffering behind the scenes or something. What does `ps` say about the memory usage of the process?

Comment: Thanks, Tom! You hit the target!
The problem was in Linux I/O buffers control mechanism. When we set the percentage of waiting buffers to 10 (by default was 40), this solved the problem and we now run already for 6 days without a problem.

Comment: @leonp: to match stackoverflow style in general, you should write your answer/experience as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the question is answered: tune the values of VM using sysctl. The essential parameters are overcommit_ratio and dirty_ratio.
UPDATE: the linux versions later than 2009 have more accurate tuning in bytes, not in percent.